# How Do I Get the Updated Position of an AnchorLayout in Kivy?

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I attempted the `do_layout()` and `_trigger_layout()` functions, but the (let's call it) `my_anchor_layout.pos` still returns `[0, 0]`, even though the `AnchorLayout()` is on its default setting to the center of the screen. How do I get the correct position of the layout as it appears on the screen? If that's not possible, is there another way to update the position of such a layout to match it's actual on-screen position?

Comment: The `anchor_x` and `anchor_y` settings refer to the position of the child of the `AnchorLayout`, not the `AnchorLayout` itself.

Comment: Okay, but when I went to the position of its one child, it also read `[0, 0]`, so it's not marking the relevant position there, either. In other words, every child is reading `[0, 0]`, even though it's clear that the child is correctly positioned at the center thanks to the `AnchorLayout()`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].